# Quantify inside group match

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to work on a regex js username checker for registration, however I'm having a few issues

This is the expression I wrote

```
^[a-zA-Z]{1}([a-zA-Z0-9]*[\._ ]?){2,10}[A-za-z\d]$
```

The problem is that it doesn't limit the period, underscore, and spaces, and also the username should be between 4-12 characters.

I'm trying to allow:
First character has to start with A-Z a-z
Last character has to be alphanumeric
Everything inbetween must be 2-10 alphanumeric characters and allowing only 1 space, period and underscore.

For example:

- A___N is not valid (3 undescores)
- A_NON is valid
- "A.Non " is not valid, space at the end.
- A.non is valid
- A N.oN is valid

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What's with the `{1}` in these newbie questions? I mean, somebody must be teaching them this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is to use a *lookahead assertion* to combine two unrelated requirements. Essentially, you need ensure that this regex *does* match:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9._ ]{2,10}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

and that this one does *not* match:

```
([._ ]).*\1
```

You can combine them by using a *negative lookahead assertion*:

```
^(?!.*([._ ]).*\1)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9._ ]{2,10}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

Comment: I tried using your expression @ http://gskinner.com/RegExr/. I understand AS3 has poor implementation, but even without the "\1" it wasn't working with my list of usernames.

^[a-zA-Z]([\._ ]?[a-zA-Z0-9]){2,10}([a-zA-Z0-9])$ was working better, but i could enter a.n.on, and ano.n wouldnt work.

Comment: @ArunForce: Sorry, I had a brain fart. In the regex that I said *does* have to match, I forgot to allow period, underscore, and space! Fixed now.

Comment: With a little modification your answer worked. Thanks!

^[a-zA-Z](?!.*([._ ]).*\1)[a-zA-Z0-9._ ]{2,10}[a-zA-Z0-9]$

Comment: @ArunForce: You're welcome! I'm glad you did such a good job creating test-cases; most people asking for regex help on StackOverflow seem to just try it on one or two strings that are supposed to match, so they never notice these sorts of mistakes. I'm glad you're smarter than that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
^(?=.{4,12}$)[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{0,10}[._ ][A-Za-z0-9]{1,10}$
```

The parentesized expression after the caret checks the length (provided your regex dialect offers lookahead assertions) or check the string length in code separately.

**Edit**: Allow number as last character. Note that this requires a space, dot, or underscore somewhere; if you make it optional, adjust the numbers accordingly.

Comment: That will allow the string to be too short (e.g., `AB`) or too long (e.g., `ABCDEFGHI_JKLMNOPQR`). Also, it will require the presence of a dot or underscore or space.

Comment: Thanks for the note; updated. I had misread the minimum length. The question is ambiguous as to whether the one punctuation character is required or optional IMHO.

Comment: It's optional. I couldn't get it work on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/, are you using a different syntax?

Comment: Works for me, apart from the optionality criterion which I haven't attempted to fix.